# angular 2 animation toggleState()

Tags: angular, animation

I am just beginning to learn Animation through angular 2. I have followed the angular2 docs on animation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html) and following the first example. It seemed very straight forward however I am getting an error when it come to calling the trigger `toggleState()`. I have viewed their plunker examples and have not found out where `toggleState()' is defined... could someone please help out...

Here is a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/CP0GEN6pRKQOlum1ZiuM?p=preview) with my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**toggleState()** is defined in *hero.service.ts*

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple of problems with your plunker.

First of all you need some styles from the beginning:

```
@Component
....
styles: [
  // your initial styles here
]
```

Then in your component you need a boolean, which will toggle the state, which was the answer you needed. Here I refer to your plunker. So first you would declare a boolean to work with:

```
toggle: boolean;
```

and in your component toggle the state e.g with a button and call the following function:

```
toggleState() {
  this.toggle = !this.toggle;
  this.stateExpression = this.toggle ? 'active':'inactive';
}
```

Then there were some problems with your animation. Then you had a error, both `states` were set as `inactive`.

Here is the [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/SWBnwwlESi1XK3KWG1KG?p=preview) with changes and some minor changes to style ;)